# Css Make all div with padding except for one?

Tags: html, css

I have all all my divs end with a space. This also affects the menu div which I do not want to have the additions padding at the end.

I tried to implement a NoEm style and use it, but of course it does nothing. As soon as I wrote it I relaised it would not affect the div. the code is here:

```
div {    
    margin-bottom: 1em; /* Adjust depending on your text's line-height */
}

div .NoEm {

}
```

So the question is:
How can I have ALL divs end with a margin except for one?

NO jquery or Js wanted.

**EDIT: HTML**

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse NoEm ">
```

**EDIT: 2**
JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jufb09m1/

**COMMENT**
Lol, so many down votes for not realising a CCS question required me to show a  html markup of `<div></div>`

Comment: where is the HTML, could you possibly provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: Without the html I can only guess you possibly wanted `div.NoEm`

Comment: @Huangism that's probably the solution, I just don't understand why people don't post markup like it's a secret or something and the people answering questions have to guess and risk losing rep.

Comment: @arniekoz dude it's all patented!!!

Comment: It is no secret but didn't think it was needed as it is a css question. But I live and learn. No need to get snippy about it.

Comment: @DaveGordon Sorry I came across that way, but CSS question or not you are just giving us nothing. CSS on it's own does not do anything, it needs HTML!

Comment: @DaveGordon if that navbar div is contained within another div then `div .NoEm` should work. It's best if you can reproduce it in a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the margin-bottom for .NoEm

```
div {    
    margin-bottom: 1em; /* Adjust depending on your text's line-height */
}
.NoEm {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use `!important`?

Comment: Good question ... now that you're commenting my whole post doesn't make sense ;) Will edit

Comment: Although according to everyone here I should actually be marking you down for not showing how it was used within the html.

Answer (score 1):

IkoTikashi's answer is correct based on the information available when they posted it; before the fiddle was available.

Now that we can see your HTML code, we can see the additional problem: In addition to not explicitly setting the margin-bottom to 0 in your .NoEm class, your navbar div contains OTHER divs. All those divs also have a margin-bottom of 1em.

You need to use the fix IkoTikashi provided of explicitly setting margin-bottom in .NoEm to 0 and you need to use that class on all the divs used to create the navbar.